# How to replace values in the main data frame using values from a lookup data frame when both of them have a common column?

Tags: r, string

I have two data frames with `dput` like this:

```
#main data frame
mydf <- structure(list(words = c("banna", "pocorn and drnk", "trael", 
                                   "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", "bing", "methog", 
                                   "tullius"), words_checking = list("banna", c("pocorn", "drnk"
                                   ), "trael", "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", 
                                   character(0), "methog", "tullius"), row_num = c("1", "2", 
                                                                                   "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  -11L), class = "data.frame")

#look up data frame
mydf_1 <- structure(list(words = c("banna", "pocorn and drnk", "pocorn and drnk", "trael", "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", "methog", "tullius"), row_num = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11"), words_checking = c("banna", "pocorn", "drnk", "trael", "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", "methog", "tullius"), suggestion = list(c("banns", "banana", "manna", "wanna", "Hanna", "bandanna", "banal", "ban"), c("popcorn", "porn", "corn"), c("drink", "drank", "drunk", "dink", "dank", "dunk"), c("trawl", "travel", "trail", "trammel"), c("rabbit", "rabbits", "Babbitt", "rabbit t", "rabbi", "terabit"), c("empty", "tempt", "temp"), c("eBay", "bay", "e bay"), c("template", "temple", "complete", "platelet"), c("intern", "internee", "internet", "interned", "interns", "intern e", "interline", "intervene", "intertwine", "interment"), c("method", "met hog", "met-hog", "methought"), "tulips"), first_suggestion = list("banns", "popcorn", "drink", "trawl", "rabbit", "empty", "eBay", "template", "intern", "method", "tulips"), second_suggestion = list("banana", "porn", "drank", "travel", "rabbits", "tempt", "bay", "temple", "internee", "met hog", NA_character_), third_suggestion = list("manna", "corn", "drunk", "trail", "Babbitt", "temp", "e bay", "complete", "internet", "met-hog", NA_character_), fourth_suggestion = list("wanna", NA_character_, "dink", "trammel", "rabbit t", NA_character_, NA_character_, "platelet", "interned", "methought", NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to use the `mydf_1$first_suggestion` column and replace the misspelled `words` column from `mydf`. I believe I can utilize the `row_num` column to do it, but not sure where to start. Anyone with experience in this can give advise?

Here is my desired output for `mydf`

```
mydf_desired <- structure(list(words = c("banna", "pocorn and drnk", "trael", 
                                         "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", "bing", "methog", "tullius"), 
                               words_checking = list("banna", c("pocorn", "drnk"), "trael", "rabbitt", "emptey", "ebay", "templete", "interne", character(0), "methog", "tullius"), 
                               row_num = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"),
                               words_first_suggestion = c("banns", "popcorn and drink", "trawl", "rabbit", "empty", "eBay", "template", "intern", "bing", "method", "tulips")), 
                          row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can `anti_join`

Comment: I don't think it's a join issue, because I have to create a new column and replace the old value with the new value from the lookup data frame. Not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: Maybe use `match` and replace but I would think an `anti_join` or `inner_join` might sufffice.

Comment: I'll look into it, but the data frame contains lists in there so it might not be joining correctly.